# Why it works about python type conversion?

Tags: python

I known if I want to do type conversion in Python, I should use the built-in functions.

for example:

```
number = int('100')
```

but I am using c# style to do conversion like

```
number = (int)('100')
```

it also work, could you tell me why that is working.

and if I try to do the same thing using the code below, it does not work.

```
number = (int)'100'
```

Answer (score 6):

Python doesn't have "type conversion"; you are passing `'100'` to the `int` **constructor**. Putting parens around the type does not change its value, but removing the parens from the type's argument means that it's no longer a constructor call but rather a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from when specifying function arguments, `(x)` is the same as `x`, so `(int)('100')` is equivalent to `int('100')`.

They even compile to the same bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: int('100'))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('100')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: (int)('100'))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('100')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int('100')
```

This means "find the object named `int`, and call it as a function, passing `'100'` as an argument".

```
(int)('100')
```

This means the same thing, since the left-hand-side is now `(int)`, which is the same as `int`, for the same reason that `(3)` is the same as `3`.

```
(int)'100'
```

By the same principle, this is the same as `int '100'`, which is a syntax error: you have two objects - the `int` class, and the string `'100'` - next to each other, with no operator or other indication of how they are supposed to interact.

Answer (score 0):

In python "int" is a class and calling "int('100')" calls the __init__ method of the int class with the argument '100'. This constructs an int object.

The expression "(int)" is no different than "int". Python has no casting/conversion operators like some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In python functions are first class objects, so `int` and `(int)` are actually the same object, the built-in function [int](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int).

```
>>> a = (int)
>>> a('100')
100
>>> a is int
True
```

You can call a function as in the example above, but not use it as a cast, c-style.